# Natural topology on space of multisets

Tags: general-topology, multisets

Let $X$ be a topological space and consider the set of all $k$ element [multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) consisting of points from $X$. Does the topology on $X$ induce a natural topology on this space of multisets?

For example, using $\langle \dots \rangle$ to denote a multiset with specified elements, I would like to be able to say things like,
$$\langle 1/n, 0, 1, 2\rangle \rightarrow \langle 0,0,1,2\rangle\quad \text{as } n \rightarrow \infty,$$

and have it be topologically meaningful.

What are the properties of such a topology on multisets? If this has been studied before, what are some good references?

This question is motivated by the following questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/665365/ways-to-induce-a-topology-on-power-set) and on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/133030/defining-a-topology-in-the-power-set) about topologies on power sets of a topological space. The difference is that in this question I'm interested in multisets rather than sets, and only multisets with a fixed cardinality, rather than all multisets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea. First, consider the Cartesian product $X^k$ endowed with the [product topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology).

It is not appropriate to identify elements of $X^k$ with the $k$-element multisets constructed from the elements of $X$, since if, for example, $k=3$, then $\langle a,a,b\rangle$ and $\langle a,b,a\rangle$ are the same multiset, whereas $(a,a,b)\neq(a,b,a)$ as elements of $X^k$ ($a,b\in X$, $a\neq b$).

However, this problem can be easily overcome by defining an equivalence relation on the elements of $X^k$ in such a way that certain distinct elements of $X^k$ are identified to conform to the structure of multisets.

Letting this equivalence relation be denoted as $\sim$, you can then try defining the [quotient topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) $X^k/\sim$ on the set of equivalence classes—that is, the set of $k$-element multisets.

---

The exact definition of $\sim$ can be formulated as follows. Suppose that $x_1,\ldots,x_k,y_1,\ldots,y_k\in X$. Let $x\equiv(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ and $y\equiv (y_1,\ldots,y_k)$. Then, we say that $x\sim y$ if there exists a permutation (a bijective function) $\pi:\{1,\ldots,k\}\to\{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $$y_i=x_{\pi(i)}\quad\text{for each $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$}.$$

Comment: Ahh interesting. So then, for example, in the case of $(\mathbb{R}^+)^K$, if you quotient out by permutations, the result could be identified with the angular cone consisting of points where the coordinates are in sorted order

Comment: @NickAlger I have not actually done the math (no pun intended), but I have a strong hunch that this quotient topology has the following property: let $\{\langle x_1^{\alpha},\ldots,x_k^{\alpha}\rangle\}_{\alpha\in A}$ be a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) (a generalized sequence) of multisets. Then, this net converges to the multiset $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_k\rangle$ in the constructed quotient topology if and only if the net $\{x_i^{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in A}$ converges to $x_i$ in the original topology for every $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$.